# How to store the contents of string array to 2 dimensional character array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

the following code asks for grid size and then takes the input values from the keyboard and stores contents in **"str"**.Now I want to store contents of "str" in a 2-dimensional character array named **char[][] board**. How do I do that? Please be patient I am new to coding.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter grid size");

int t = s.nextInt(); // read number of elements
s.nextLine(); // consume new line
System.out.println("Enter the values");
int d = s.nextInt(); // read number of elements
s.nextLine();
String str[] = new String[t];
for(int k=0;k<t;k++) {
         str[k]=s.nextLine();
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter grid size
3
Enter the values
123
234
456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the length of all the strings inputted is the same, or else it will cause an error. While creating a 2D array, we have to specify the rows and columns. To get the column size, we try to find the length of the first string input.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Enter grid size") ;

    int size = in.nextInt() ;  // size is the total number of incoming strings

    String str = in.next() ;
    int col = str.length()  ; // getting the length of the fisrt string to get column size for the grid

    char grid[][] = new char[size][col] ;
    grid[0] = str.toCharArray() ;  

    for (int i = 1 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        str = in.next() ; 
        grid[i] = str.toCharArray() ; 
    }
```

If you just need to read or go through (NOT edit/change) the characters of strings, you can use `str.charAt(index`) method. You won't need to create a 2D array char[][] 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you need, is "probably":

```
// so far so good...
// not: String str[] = new String[t];, but:
char [][] str = new char[t][];
for(int k=0;k<t;k++) {
     str[k] = s.nextLine().toCharArray();
}
```

So:

1. Change the type of `str` to `char[t][]`.
2. Set each `str[k]` to `String.toCharArray();` (where `String` is `s.nextLine()`).

See javadoc: [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--)

Comment: Thank you very much